# Reversing the order of Outer

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I'm trying to use a function with two slots that I want to map over lists of different lengths and I think Outer is the function I need to solve the problem.

I tried the following example:

```
Outer[f,{1,2,3},{1,2}]
```

> `{{f[1, 1], f[1, 2]}, {f[2, 1], f[2, 2]}, {f[3, 1], f[3, 2]}}`

I need it to return

> `{{f[1,1], f[2,1], f[3,1], f[1,2], f[2,2], f[3,2]}}`

Comment: Have you seen `Transpose[]`?

Comment: `{Reverse /@ Flatten@Outer[f, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}]}`

Comment: @J.M. "Easily found in the documentation?"

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, not really sure, but I have been using `Transpose[]` for a long while that it feels natural. Using `Outer[]` with a reversed function is something that could've come easily to the OP, tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a community wiki where we can accumulate answers.

happy fish

```
{Reverse /@ Flatten @ Outer[f, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}]}
```

m_goldberg

```
{Flatten[Table[f[j, i], {i, 2}, {j, 3}]]}
```

J. M.

```
Outer[f[#2, #] &, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

In addition,

```
Distribute[{{1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, List, List, List, Reverse @* f]
```

Or, via a `Transpose`, as

```
{Flatten @ Transpose @ Outer[f, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}]}
```

Comment: ...or, since the OP wants `Outer[]`, just feed it the reversed function as the first argument: `Outer[f[#2, #1] &, (* stuff *)]`. But I prefer `Transpose[]`.